# Trying to integrat inMobi banners while using mopub's ios-robovm-bindings

Tags: java, objective-c, robovm, mopub, inmobi

I'm using robovm to develop iOS game while using Java.

I'm trying to use Mopub's ios-robovm-bindings (https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings/tree/master/mopub) to integrate inmobi banner ads to my app but with no luck so far.

I keep getting this message:

```
Oct 12 22:00:59 Asafs-iPhone IOSLauncher[5113] <Warning>: MOPUB: Looking for custom event class named InMobiBannerCustomEvent.
Oct 12 22:00:59 Asafs-iPhone IOSLauncher[5113] <Warning>: MOPUB: Requesting InMobi banner
Oct 12 22:00:59 Asafs-iPhone IOSLauncher[5113] <Warning>: MOPUB: Failed to create an inMobi Banner with invalid size {7.1806318e-37, 5.9439283e-15}
```

I already made changes in Mopub's web UI by entering a CUSTOM EVENT CLASS and CUSTOM EVENT CLASS DATA with my inmobi "app_id".

Do I need to add size as well? if so, how?

I would greatly appreciate any help in working this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from InMobi.

> Failed to create an inMobi Banner with invalid size {7.1806318e-37,
>   5.9439283e-15}

Looks like you've specified the wrong ad sizes. It shouldn't be in decimals. Just specify the correct ad sizes as mentioned in the documentation and it should work.